IRS error impact during different flight phases
I am working on my thesis on the Inertial Reference System and its errors and accuracy. I am struggling to find if the errors (biases, drifts, ARW, scale factors, etc.) have different impacts on the system during different flight phases (like if the position errors produced during takeoff could be bigger than during cruising). I need it with a source - a book, science journal, article, or something like that. Any help would be much appreciated.

There is a study which presents the errors vs. the maneuver parameters, by Paul D Groves for IEEE: Navigation using Inertial Sensors
